# parsing and creating new data set for a selected Mainstep

Tags: python-3.x

I have huge data file with strings as heading for each column. Among those 17 columns, the 2nd column has `MainSteps`, which I want to use to plot the parameters present in the remaining columns. For example:

```
column1 column2     cloumn3    column4    column5   column6   column7 ......
num1    Mainstep1    num3       num5       num7
num2    Mainstep1    num4       num6       ...
...     ...          ...        ...        ...

...     Mainstep2    ...       ...         ...
```

The requirement is to parse according to `Mainstep1`, then get all the parameters recorded from the csv file for only that `Mainstep1`. With those parameters, plot between `column1` vs. `column3` or `column5` vs. `column6`.

I am new to programming. Sometimes I struggle to find accurate words that programmers use to ask questions. Please ask if clarification is needed in terms of the question meaning.

The preferred output is to print all the data of two parameters of x- and y-axis corresponding to a specific `Mainstep`. I hope I have clarity in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like below using pandas work for you?

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.read_csv('/location/to/so_sample.csv', sep='\t')
filtered_df = my_df[my_df.column2=='Mainstep1']
```

Basically, filtered_df would contain all rows where column2 is Mainstep1. You can call

```
filtered_df.column1
filtered_df.column3
```

to get the desired set of rows to plot the charts